# Conditional compiling in Ionic/Cordova App

Tags: android, angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework

I am using Ionic/Cordova/ngCordova to build a simple HTLM5 app.

I have the below sample code

```
<form novalidate>
    <input type='text' name='text' required>
</form>
```

Now I want the input to only be "required" when either running in the dev browser (Which is easy) or when running a debug build in Android (Tricky) .

How can I achieve this ?

Comment: If you have a scope variable, say `$scope.isRequired`, that is set to `true` based on the build type (how you get the build type, I don't know), then you could just use `ng-required="isRequired"`

Comment: Getting the build type is the tricky part.

Comment: Sure... it might as well be, but then, it's not related to Angular... so, your question has 2 independent parts: 1) how to get the build type and 2) how to conditionally make an input required based on that. You should ask then 2 separate questions (or research each one) to increase your chances of solving this. Piling multiple issues into a single question is not the best way to go

Comment: Two ideas: You could use a hook in cordova or you can run a gradle script in Android Studio. Have a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27861169/android-studio-build-type-release-debug-what-relevance-does-this-have In these scripts you can inject or replace code.