# What is the difference between a debugged version android apk and a release non-debugged version android apk?

Tags: android, apk

What are some notable differences that a developer should take note?

Comment: May I ask why the negative vote? Please explain so that I can improve the quality of my questions in future.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first one is debuggable and the second one isn't.

That means that the first one will output all your `Log.d`'s and the production version won't.

Also, by default, debug versions are compiled without ProGuard while production builds are compiled using the default ProGuard rules

Comment: I presume the non-debuggable version is faster and smaller, right?

Comment: @user1824987 Yes, ProGuard strips off unnecessary code and will reduce the package size (noticeable mainly if you use a lot of libraries). It's also faster since the App doesn't output all the log information.
Keep in mind that there are some weird cases were your app might work as a debug build but not when it's compiled as a production version. **Always** test the production version before publication ;-)

Answer (score 1):

you may take a look at those posts

[Android Studio: Build type release /debug - what relevance does this have?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27861169/android-studio-build-type-release-debug-what-relevance-does-this-have)

also the officiel documentation is clear and hepful
http://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/app-signing.html

**hint**

> **debug** when you are working on the project
>
> **release** when you are about to publish the app

good luck !

Answer (score 1):

One of the most important differences is that debug version of app **is not prguarded** so it can be reverse engineered. The reason why it's not proguarded is because you can track your logcat outputs easily without need to check mapping files.

> In debug mode, you sign your app with a debug certificate generated by the Android SDK tools. This certificate has a private key with a known password, so you can run and debug your app without typing the password every time you make a change to your project.